# How to Solve cross origin domain access error on laravel and vue js

Tags: laravel, dns, hosting

I am creating an app with larvel and vue js. It is in two separate directories. one is larvel and vue js and the other is vue. I am trying to access some apis from vue.js directory located at the second directory. On local it was working fine but on go daddy server it says:

Chrome:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maindirectory(larvel)' from origin 'https://(second directory)vue.js' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

On Firefox it says:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://directory1/api/seller/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

I have tried almost every solution available on the internet:
i have placed these headers:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, X-Authorization,X-CSRF-Token,api_token');
header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Authorization, Authorization');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');

In routes.php , api.php
and also tried setting headers in web.config   and .htaccess.

But nothing helped. I have been stuck for four days. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ahve also tried adding these

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, X-Authorization,X-CSRF-Token,api_token'); header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Authorization, Authorization'); header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');                 to    bootstrap/app.php     and tried adding this  package  barryvdh/laravel-cors    and    created a  cors middleware but nothing helps

Comment: have you checked your cors.php file

Comment: If this is a new project then refer to https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#cors if this is an old project then you either need to use https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors (if under version 9.2) or refer to the current boilerplate code in [Kernel.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/app/Http/Kernel.php) on how to use the correct middleware. Sometimes you may see CORS errors because there are other errors hiding underneath. Try the request in POSTMAN to see if it works normally without CORS

Comment: Yes i ahve checked cors. @BhargavRangani.   its laravel  7.

Comment: change this variable in that file  'allowed_origins_patterns' => [], to     'allowed_origins_patterns' => [*]

Comment: tried that too @BhargavRangani